# Convert SVG path of a glyph to the character the glyph represents

Tags: javascript, svg, ocr

[This](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/xxJaGjE?editors=1000) working CodePen demo shows a number which is represented as a vector.

May I ask how to convert the number vector (SVG Format) as shown in demo to a real number?

From my search on the web, Tesseract do not read vector graphics (SVG), can anyone show some demo or samples of how to read number vector?

For Example, this vector graphics code below should be read as a number 9 in the console.log

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="0 0 1066.6667 800"
   height="800"
   width="1066.6667"
   xml:space="preserve"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"><metadata
     id="metadata8"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
         rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
     id="defs6" /><g
     transform="matrix(1.3333333,0,0,-1.3333333,0,800)"
     id="g10"><path
       id="path20"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.074;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 294.09,426.05 -0.46,-1.38 -0.92,-0.92 -1.38,-0.46 h -0.46 l -1.37,0.46 -0.92,0.92 -0.46,1.38 v 0.46 l 0.46,1.37 0.92,0.92 1.37,0.46 h 0.46 l 1.38,-0.46 0.92,-0.92 0.46,-1.83 v -2.3 l -0.46,-2.29 -0.92,-1.38 -1.38,-0.46 h -0.91 l -1.38,0.46 -0.46,0.92" /></g></svg>
```

Comment: There is no relationship between the path data and the number 9 other than that's roughly the shape of the path. Look up the game "connect the dots" to get a better understanding of how an svg works.

Comment: So you already know to use Tesseract? Then the question is how to convert SVG to PNG, right?

Comment: @SebastianSimon, Hi Sebastion,the reason why I don't convert SVG to PNG because it will lose its image quality, because my the SVG image is pretty big with little texts on it which if I were to convert to image file, it will be very blur which is unreadable by Tesseract OCR :)

Comment: Vector file (SVG) will not lose its quality and every single text are displayed clearly, unlike image file (PNG or JPG) :)

Comment: But you only need the raster image for Tesseract. You don’t _lose_ your vector graphic in any way.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, hi, my SVG code is a little bit too long to be uploaded here :), so I have shared this pdf of a ground floor plan, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OyOdzSmmCYZ8JRVx15SLBYJhyenkAqlZ/view?usp=sharing,  and you can convert the pdf to svg file using this online converter https://cloudconvert.com/pdf-to-svg, however, when I try to convert SVG file to even the highest quality image (JPG or PNG) using online converters, it losses its text quality significantly and becomes blur as you zoom in which is a problem to Tesseract OCR :)

Comment: @SebastianSimon, i think i will probably go for extracting text from pdf, wouldn't that be even easier and I believe there are OCR for pdf right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented, you need to **convert the svg to a raster image for OCR**.

Fortunately we have a lot of options to create a bitmap temporarily using `<canvas>`.

Apart from the fact, tesseract's OCR might struggle with different shapes, low contrasts – you might not get the desired result, if your svg contains many shapes.

#### Single Glyph

```js
svg2PngAndOCR("svg");

function svg2PngAndOCR(selector) {
  const svgEl = document.querySelector(selector);
  let viewBox = svgEl.viewBox.baseVal;
  let svgBB = svgEl.getBBox();
  let svgW = viewBox.width ? viewBox.width : svgBB.width;
  let svgH = viewBox.height ? viewBox.height : svgBB.height;

  /**
   * convert svg to png via canvas
   */
  let blob = new Blob([svgEl.outerHTML], { type: "image/svg+xml" });
  let URL = window.URL;
  let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  let tmpImg = new Image();
  tmpImg.src = blobURL;
  tmpImg.width = svgW;
  tmpImg.height = svgH;

  tmpImg.onload = () => {
    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = svgW;
    canvas.height = svgH;
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(tmpImg, 0, 0, svgW, svgH);
    let pngDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    let svgImg = document.createElement("img");
    svgImg.width = svgW;
    svgImg.height = svgH;
    svgImg.class = "svgImg";
    svgImg.src = pngDataUrl;

    // just additional wrapping for example usage
    let imgWrp = document.querySelector('.img-wrp');
    if(!imgWrp){
      imgWrp =  document.createElement("div");
      imgWrp.setAttribute("class", "img-wrp img-wrp-vanilla");
      imgWrp.appendChild(svgImg);
      document.body.appendChild(imgWrp);
    }

    /**
     * OCR: recognize text
     * via tesseract
     */
    Tesseract.recognize(svgImg, "eng", {
      //logger: (m) => console.log(m)
    }).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
        ocrOutput.textContent = text;
    });
  };
}
```

```css
svg,
.img-wrp
{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  width:40%;
  height:auto;
  display:inline-block;
}

img{
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.hidden{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src='https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js@4.0.2/dist/tesseract.min.js'></script>
<p>OCR Output: <span id="ocrOutput"></span></p>

<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1066.6667 800" height="800" width="1066.6667" xml:space="preserve" id="svg2" version="1.1">
  <metadata id="metadata8">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs id="defs6" />
  <g transform="matrix(1.3333333,0,0,-1.3333333,0,800)" id="g10">
    <path id="path20" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.074;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" d="m 294.09,426.05 -0.46,-1.38 -0.92,-0.92 -1.38,-0.46 h -0.46 l -1.37,0.46 -0.92,0.92 -0.46,1.38 v 0.46 l 0.46,1.37 0.92,0.92 1.37,0.46 h 0.46 l 1.38,-0.46 0.92,-0.92 0.46,-1.83 v -2.3 l -0.46,-2.29 -0.92,-1.38 -1.38,-0.46 h -0.91 l -1.38,0.46 -0.46,0.92" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

#### Multiple elements

```js
svg2PngAndOCR("svg");

function svg2PngAndOCR(selector) {
  const svgEl = document.querySelector(selector);
  let viewBox = svgEl.viewBox.baseVal;
  let svgBB = svgEl.getBBox();
  let svgW = viewBox.width ? viewBox.width : svgBB.width;
  let svgH = viewBox.height ? viewBox.height : svgBB.height;

  /**
   * convert svg to png via canvas
   */
  let blob = new Blob([svgEl.outerHTML], { type: "image/svg+xml" });
  let URL = window.URL;
  let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  let tmpImg = new Image();
  tmpImg.src = blobURL;
  tmpImg.width = svgW;
  tmpImg.height = svgH;

  tmpImg.onload = () => {
    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = svgW;
    canvas.height = svgH;
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(tmpImg, 0, 0, svgW, svgH);
    let pngDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    let svgImg = document.createElement("img");
    svgImg.width = svgW;
    svgImg.height = svgH;
    svgImg.class = "svgImg";
    svgImg.src = pngDataUrl;

    // just additional wrapping for example usage
    let imgWrp = document.querySelector('.img-wrp');
    if(!imgWrp){
      imgWrp =  document.createElement("div");
      imgWrp.setAttribute("class", "img-wrp img-wrp-vanilla");
      imgWrp.appendChild(svgImg);
      document.body.appendChild(imgWrp);
    }

    /**
     * OCR: recognize text
     * via tesseract
     */
    Tesseract.recognize(svgImg, "eng", {
      //logger: (m) => console.log(m)
    }).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
        ocrOutput.textContent = text;
    });
  };
}
```

```css
svg,
.img-wrp
{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  width:40%;
  height:auto;
  display:inline-block;
}

img{
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.hidden{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src='https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js@4.0.2/dist/tesseract.min.js'></script>

<p>OCR Output: <span id="ocrOutput"></span></p>

<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1066.6667 800" height="800" width="1066.6667" xml:space="preserve" id="svg2" version="1.1">
  <metadata id="metadata8">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs id="defs6" />
  <g transform="matrix(1.3333333,0,0,-1.3333333,0,800)" id="g10">
    <path id="path20" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" d="m 294.09,426.05 -0.46,-1.38 -0.92,-0.92 -1.38,-0.46 h -0.46 l -1.37,0.46 -0.92,0.92 -0.46,1.38 v 0.46 l 0.46,1.37 0.92,0.92 1.37,0.46 h 0.46 l 1.38,-0.46 0.92,-0.92 0.46,-1.83 v -2.3 l -0.46,-2.29 -0.92,-1.38 -1.38,-0.46 h -0.91 l -1.38,0.46 -0.46,0.92" />
  </g>
  
<path id="hello" transform="scale(1)" class="glyph" d="M4.8 200.5h-0.9v-3.3h-3v3.3h-0.9v-6.9h0.9v2.8h3v-2.8h0.9v6.9zm5.9-2.8q0 0.2 0 0.4l0 0h-3.4q0.1 0.9 0.5 1.3t1 0.4l0 0q0.4 0 0.7-0.1t0.6-0.3l0 0l0.4 0.5q-0.8 0.7-1.8 0.7l0 0q-1.1 0-1.7-0.7q-0.6-0.8-0.6-2l0 0q0-0.8 0.2-1.5q0.3-0.6 0.8-1q0.5-0.3 1.2-0.3l0 0q1 0 1.6 0.7q0.5 0.6 0.5 1.9l0 0zm-0.9-0.2v-0.1q0-0.8-0.3-1.2t-0.9-0.4l0 0q-1.1 0-1.3 1.7l0 0h2.5zm3.5 3.1q-0.6 0-0.9-0.3q-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.9l0 0v-6.3l0.9-0.1v6.4q0 0.2 0 0.3q0.1 0.1 0.3 0.1l0 0q0.2 0 0.3 0l0 0l0.3 0.6q-0.3 0.2-0.7 0.2l0 0zm2.9 0q-0.5 0-0.8-0.3t-0.3-0.9l0 0v-6.3l0.9-0.1v6.4q0 0.2 0.1 0.3q0 0.1 0.2 0.1l0 0q0.2 0 0.4 0l0 0l0.2 0.6q-0.3 0.2-0.7 0.2l0 0zm3.8-5.5q1.1 0 1.8 0.7q0.6 0.7 0.6 2l0 0q0 0.8-0.3 1.5q-0.3 0.6-0.8 0.9q-0.5 0.4-1.3 0.4l0 0q-1.1 0-1.7-0.8q-0.6-0.7-0.6-2l0 0q0-0.8 0.3-1.4q0.2-0.6 0.8-1q0.5-0.3 1.2-0.3l0 0zm0 0.7q-1.3 0-1.3 2l0 0q0 2 1.3 2l0 0q1.4 0 1.4-2l0 0q0-2-1.4-2l0 0zm12.7-2.2h0.9l-1.4 6.9h-1.2l-1.3-5.8l-1.3 5.8h-1.2l-1.4-6.9h1l1.1 6l1.3-6h1l1.4 6l1.1-6zm4.1 1.5q1.1 0 1.7 0.7t0.6 2l0 0q0 0.8-0.2 1.5q-0.3 0.6-0.9 0.9q-0.5 0.4-1.2 0.4l0 0q-1.1 0-1.8-0.8q-0.6-0.7-0.6-2l0 0q0-0.8 0.3-1.4t0.8-1q0.5-0.3 1.3-0.3l0 0zm0 0.7q-1.4 0-1.4 2l0 0q0 2 1.4 2l0 0q1.3 0 1.3-2l0 0q0-2-1.3-2l0 0zm6.1-0.7q0.3 0 0.6 0l0 0l-0.2 0.9q-0.2 0-0.5 0l0 0q-0.5 0-0.8 0.3q-0.3 0.4-0.4 1.1l0 0v3.1h-0.9v-5.3h0.7l0.1 1.1q0.2-0.6 0.6-0.9t0.8-0.3l0 0zm2.7 5.5q-0.5 0-0.8-0.3t-0.3-0.9l0 0v-6.3l0.9-0.1v6.4q0 0.2 0.1 0.3q0 0.1 0.2 0.1l0 0q0.2 0 0.4 0l0 0l0.2 0.6q-0.3 0.2-0.7 0.2l0 0zm5-7.6l0.9 0.1v7.4h-0.8l-0.1-0.8q-0.2 0.4-0.6 0.6q-0.4 0.3-0.9 0.3l0 0q-0.9 0-1.5-0.8q-0.5-0.7-0.5-2l0 0q0-0.8 0.3-1.4q0.2-0.6 0.7-1q0.5-0.3 1.1-0.3l0 0q0.8 0 1.4 0.6l0 0v-2.7zm-1.3 6.8q0.4 0 0.7-0.2q0.3-0.1 0.6-0.5l0 0v-2.6q-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.5q-0.2-0.2-0.6-0.2l0 0q-0.6 0-1 0.5q-0.3 0.5-0.3 1.5l0 0q0 1 0.3 1.5t0.9 0.5l0 0z " />

<use href="#hello" x="200" transform="scale(2)"/>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for such a detailed answer, I have copied your code on to codepen at https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/gOjdErB?editors=1010, and it seems like the l in World (Small Word) is read as t. The big word (World) is read perfectly. So, I guess this tesseract has its own limitations too?

Comment: My solution I am thinking of is I can actually determine the numbers or characters involved( the svg file I am reading has a constant letter style, just that the size of letter might change), so I would actually hardcode the SVG path of the letter 9, and then scale it accordingly to see it matches other letter 9 which is smaller that is harder to be read by OCR?

Comment: Do you think that's a solution? Oh and I forgot have to include vertical and horizontal or even slanting rotation for each number and try to match the hardcoded path of each number :) ?

Comment: Rotation is most certainly a bummer ... I'm afraid, the best you can get is a rather semi-automatic workflow: E.g 1. catching actually readable svg `<text>`  elements 2. removing them for raster image based OCR 3. recognize rasterized `<path>` elements via tesseract OCR. Scaling and increasing contrast (e.g. by changing fills strokes to black and increasing `stroke-width`) will certainly help – but there is not easy way to do so if element sizes vary too much.   So ... you have to test it. Besides, there are certainly more advanced tesseract options to check.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough cut but keep in mind that OCR is not always 100% accurate, and the results will be poor if the svg is too abstract.

```
// Convert to a base64 encoded image
const inputSvg = '<svg><path fill="black" d="m 294.09,426.05 -0.46,-1.38 -0.92,-0.92 -1.38,-0.46 h -0.46 l -1.37,0.46 -0.92,0.92 -0.46,1.38 v 0.46 l 0.46,1.37 0.92,0.92 1.37,0.46 h 0.46 l 1.38,-0.46 0.92,-0.92 0.46,-1.83 v -2.3 l -0.46,-2.29 -0.92,-1.38 -1.38,-0.46 h -0.91 l -1.38,0.46 -0.46,0.92" /></svg>';
const inputBase64Image = Buffer.from(inputSvg).toString('base64');

// Convert the encoded image to a buffer
const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(inputBase64Image, 'base64');

// Convert the buffer to a png
sharp(imageBuffer)
  .png()
  .toBuffer()
  .then(buffer => {
    console.log('SVG converted to PNG buffer');

    // Configure the recognition process
    const config = {
      lang: 'eng',
      oem: 1,
      psm: 3,
    };

    // Recognise the character
    tesseract.recognize(buffer, config)
      .then(character => {
        console.log("What is 6 + 3?", character);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I have tried to use your code in my demo https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/ZEjMVMj?editors=1010, but it says error "Buffer not defined", how do i solve this ? :)

Comment: Hi buzz, the code above relies on node and packages, i.e.
const sharp = require('sharp');
const tesseract = require('node-tesseract-ocr');

I understand that you're eager to tackle this task, but it could require a level of technical knowledge that you haven't yet acquired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a machine learning or computer vision library such as TensorFlow.js or OpenCV. These libraries allow you to train a model using labelled examples of characters and then use the model to classify new, unseen characters based on their visual appearance.

Here's a high-level overview of the process:

1. Prepare a dataset of labelled examples of characters in the form of SVGs.
2. Train a machine learning model, such as a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN), using the labelled examples.
3. Use the trained model to classify new, unseen SVGs by running them through the model and determining the most likely character based on the model's output.

Keep in mind that this is a complex task and requires a solid understanding of machine learning and computer vision. If you are new to these fields, you may want to start with some tutorials or courses to familiarize yourself with the concepts before attempting to build a character recognition system.

https://www.tensorflow.org/js

https://opencv.org